# Filezilla FTP server - change directory gets failed from client (command-prompt, java)

Tags: windows, ftp, command-prompt, filezilla, ftp-server

I had setup Filezilla FTP server in my PC and tried to ftp from local machine itself. I could connect, transfer files ,but couldn't change the remote directory.

By default it lands on home directory( D:/FTP) and can change (cd) to sub-directories under the home directory.. however i need to access the folders/files outside (D:/test) the home directory any suggestions?

```
D:\FTP>ftp localhost
Connected to XXXXXX.
220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.39 beta
220 xxxx ftp server
User (XXXXXXX:(none)): xsds
331 Password required for xsxs
Password:
230 Logged on
ftp> pwd
257 "/" is current directory.
ftp> cd D:
**550 CWD failed. "/D:": directory not found.**
ftp>
```

Answer (score 0):

With FTP you can not change to a directory that is outside your home directory. If you need access to other files change your home directory accordingly.